# Removed margins above and below a <div> element?

Tags: html, css

I've come across a strange behavior related to the margins of a `<div>` element. [I've added a very simple test case to jsFiddle to show you what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/PptDn/).

Interestingly the margins are used correctly when using a border. Is this the default behavior? Does this have something to do with collapsing margins? Is it possible to somehow force the margins without any hacks?

**Least ugly solution so far that I thought of:**

```
.cssContainer {
    margin:10px;
    padding:0.1px;

    background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

But I don't know whether this will work in every browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another case of adding `overflow:auto` to the rescue!

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PptDn/4/)**

Just add `overflow:auto` to your container div and voila, harmony is restored.

```
.cssContainer {
    margin:10px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

From [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins), the reason this works is because a new *block formatting context* is established by applying `overflow` other than `visible`, forcing margins of `.cssContainer` to not collapse with its in-flow children `.cssElement`.

Comment: Could you provide any background on why this actually works? Because I can't see any reason why this is fixing it - but it does. And as log as I don't understand it, it for me is still considered quite hackish.

Comment: I'm about to leave work so I'm not sure I'll get a change to leave a formal explanation. In short, I'm thinking it works for the same reason you use it to clear a floated child div from a parent.

Comment: Sounds legit to me. Best solution so far and if there isn't a better one within the next few days I am going to accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: This works in Firefox 3.5 (possibly earlier), Chrome 6 (possibly earlier) and IE7 - IE10 see: http://browsershots.org/requests/7919289

Answer (score 2):

From [this site](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)

> the simplest way to stop the margin collapse from occurring is to add
>   padding or borders to each element. If we wanted 10px margins on each
>   element we could simply use a 9px margin and 1px of padding to get the
>   result we wanted

Comment: I already thought of this, but in my eyes it is a pretty ugly solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the [CSS box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). The elements with the red backgrounds will not grow in height to accommodate the top and bottom padding of its children elements, but because the border was specified in the second example and encompasses the padding, the padding will show.

The `overflow: auto;` property works because the padding overflows its parent element.  To illustrate this, in Google Chrome Developer Tools, find and click the HTML row for the green element whose bottom padding will not show.  Chrome will highlight the element on the page.  Notice how the padding is included in the highlighted element.  The padding actually overflows the parent element.  The parent element won't show it though because there's no content in or after the padding (no 'bounds').

Comment: Thanks for providing the reason of the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

From the [css spec regarding box models](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html):

> Adjoining vertical margins collapse, except:
>
> ...
>
> Horizontal margins never collapse.
>
> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>     top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child
>     bottom margin of box and top margin of its next in-flow following sibling
>     bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent if the parent has 'auto' computed height
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ***Note** the above rules imply that:*
>
> ...
>
> Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such
>   as floats and elements with '[overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-overflow)' other than 'visible') do not
>   collapse with their in-flow children.

Unfortunately, `text-overflow: auto` is slightly risky [because the spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#propdef-overflow):

> #### auto
>
> The behavior of the 'auto' value is user agent-dependent, 
>   but should cause a scrolling mechanism to be provided for overflowing boxes

However, all browsers that I have looked at appear to implement it in the following manner:

The box is expanded to the smaller amount between:

1. as much as its containing box allows
2. as much as is necessary to display the content without clipping

Then if clipping must occur, a scrollbar is added.